# How to get json as output from dynamic form

Tags: json, jsp, servlets

I want to enter marks for subject,no of subject is generated from db,
so i have mark object has follow:

```
class Mark
{
    int subCode;
    int internal;
    int oral;
    int term;

  //....getter and setter method
 }
```

in form for exp,I have 6 Subject
so in my jsp code

```
        <%
        for ( int i =0 ; i<6 ; i++){
        %>
        <input type="hidden"  name="subCode" value="<%=i%>"  >
        Internal : <input type="number" name='internal' >
oral : <input type="number" name='oral' >
term : <input type="number" name='term' >
   <% } %>
  <input type="submit">
```

so how to pass that 6 Mark object into another servlet for processing using JSON.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you are sure there will be 6 dynamic text boxed, why not do like this:

JSP:

```
<input type="hidden"  name="noSubject" value="${noSubject}">
<c:forEach var="i" begin="1" end="${noSubject}">
  <input type="hidden"  name="subCode${i}" value="${i}">
  Internal : <input type="number" name="internal${i}" >
  oral : <input type="number" name="oral${i}" >
  term : <input type="number" name="term${i}" >   
</c:forEach>
```

Servlet

```
List<Mark> marksList= new ArrayList<Mark>();
int noSubject = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("noSubject");
for(int i=1; i< noSubject + 1; i++){
   int subCode=Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("subCode"+i));
   int internal=Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("internal"+i));
   int oral=Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("oral"+i));
   int term=Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("term"+i));
   Mark mark = new Mark();
   mark.setSubCode(subCode);
   ...//more setters
   marksList.add(mark);
}
```

Comment: what if, that subject count is generated from database.It is dyanamic for that student,as per no of subject assigned to that student

Comment: How to use json in it

Comment: You could send the no of subject count in the request scope and loop that many times. See the updated answer.